# Fatal error when initializing core config

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am a rookie in hyperledger in China.

I followed the order of the official documents

My fabric version is up to date （2020.10.10）and I attend a error when i carry out this moment：

`./network.sh deployCC`,

I found an answer in the official documentation, and have an error in `test-network`.

I carried out `fabric-samples/facar/startFabric.sh` and carried out `peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryAllCars"]}'` in `test-network` directory.

However, there is a new problem:

`fatal error when initializing core config : Could not find config file. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set to a path which contains core.yaml`,

I set up this path already, why?

My English is not very good, I'm sorry `:(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is came from this file:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/v2.1.1/test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh

Check line 16 which is "**FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/**" and make sure you have the config folder on that directory.

Inside that config folder, you may find core.yaml, configtx.yaml, orderer.yaml.

After install samples, binaries and docker images, you can find this config folder in "fabric-samples" directory.

To install samples, binaries and docker images, go to this link:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/install.html#install-samples-binaries-and-docker-images

Comment: thank you very much,Can I put ```configtx.yaml core.yaml orderer.yaml``` in ```FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/ ```folder

Comment: It's your choice but you must need to put core.yaml on that folder. Actually fabric has plugable architecture, so you can decorate as your wish.

Comment: another question,friend,when i carry out ```peer chaincode list```
error come out
```Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /home/peng/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/scripts/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo```
what can i do for it? :(

Comment: Please check, you clear previous setup and generate all the crypto material properly.

Comment: always check if export FABRIC_CFG_PATH points correctly to config file

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to set the environment variable. In the command line, set

`export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/config/`

or wherever your `config` directory is relative to your current working directory and then try again.